# How to add text and images statically and dynamically on aspx page in my situation

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, master-pages

I am beginner to ASP.NET and its my first application which has view like this : http://prntscr.com/5iaiig

Here you can see that its bit similar to facebook with a difference that i want to simply demonstrate different texts on click to each button like "Home", "About", "TimeLine" and "Photo".
I dont know how to do that ?

My all code for Site.Mater is :

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>
                  <img src="Images/sss.jpg" alt="Powered by Shekhar" width="80" height="100" />
                    Shekhar's FaceBuk                   
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="loginDisplay">
                <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                        [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/> ]
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>
            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="TimeLine"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Photos"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="testing of shekhar" />
                    </Items>    
                </asp:Menu>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Whereas important part is :

```
<div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="TimeLine"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Photos"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="testing of shekhar" />
                    </Items>    
                </asp:Menu>
            </div>
```

In my About.aspx the two .cs files are :
About.aspx.cs  and About.aspx.designer.cs they are as follows respectively :

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class About : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the number of labels to create.

        }
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class About
    {
    }
}
```

Now question is how to change these **two classes** and **Site.Maser** so that i can display some contents(text, image etc) on click to "About" in the just below (I have to do same for each button click but once i got idea for one i can do for others)? Thanks would be a big helping hand for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you never need to bother with the designer.cs files. And if all you need to do is display contents like text, image, etc, then you don't need to bother with the *.cs files at all. Just put the markup directly in the about.aspx page. Wrap it inside of an asp:Content tag so that it gets included in with your master page, like so:

About.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="About.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.About" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h1>About Us</h1>
    <p>We code in HTML5 and CSS3</p>
    <img src="/images/logo.gif" />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: when i click on About.aspx it gives this : http://prntscr.com/5ihsge So hoz i can add the code (that you wrote) in About.aspx

Comment: You can't open the page directly through the file system, i.e. C:\users\...\about.aspx. You have to run it through a web server. In Visual Studio you can press the play button to load up the web server (IIS express) which will display the site and process your aspx pages. In fact, in your first screenshot it shows the url http://localhost:58017 being used, which I am assuming you got there by pressing that play button. But in your second screenshot it looks like you are browsing there through the file system which won't work.

Comment: I tried to open About.aspx by directly clicking on it then it gave this error. But why i understand from your comments is : (1) I should click on play button it will go to my browser and will show the website and then i put your code on website on "About" button click. Coukd you please correct me if i am wrong. (I am bit confused). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Infact i have got this on run : http://localhost:58017/About.aspx .So you mean that i have to put the pasted code of yours at the area where  "Put Contents here" is written. But it is not possible to do because when i cannot paste anything there (Its not any textblock, so that it recieve any text).

Comment: I can't see where you have "Put Contents here" written. You would add the code I wrote to the aspx page in Visual Studio. Then when you press the play button and click on the About link, you should see the html content that is within the asp:Content area.

Comment: Please see i get this when i press Play"http://prntscr.com/5in07e", Now perhaps u can see "Put contents here". By play button do you mean this button http://prntscr.com/5in45f ? (perhaps i am confused).What i tried is (1) I clicked this button and i had in browser the view whose snapshot i just shown. where we have "Put contents here" just below the "About" on click to it (2) After i directly clicked on About.aspx and it took me directly on internet explorer where i have http://prntscr.com/5in7o4 .Could you please let me know where i am wrong ?

Comment: Yes that is the correct play button. The "Put Contents here" looks like it would be in the markup in your about.aspx page within Visual Studio. You can edit it from within Visual Studio and then reload your page to see the results. But, for some reason your link that points to About.aspx sends you to the filesystem path instead of just /About.aspx. I don't know why that is happening. Maybe try changing the NavigateUrl in your asp:Menu to just /About.aspx (instead of ~/About.aspx).

Comment: The problem was: Being a beginner i didnt saw View MarkUp option on right click to About.aspx file. Now its working thanks for your try.